# How to keep text format with an hyperlink?

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, string-formatting, number-formatting, google-sheets-formula

When I add a hyperlink on a cell the number formatting goes away. How to keep the formating with a hyperlink?

eg: `12356,789` formatted to `12 356,8` (with `#,##0.0`) loose is formatting after adding a hyperlink on the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like:

```
=HYPERLINK("www.xxx.ca", TEXT(A23, "#,##0.0"))
```

[image: 0]